# OpenGL - rotating around 2 axes using glm

Tags: opengl, rotation, glm-math

I have created 2 cylinders that i wish to rotate using the following code:

```
glm::vec3 randVec3 = { 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f };
glm::vec3 randVec4 = { 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f };
d_tfms[i] = glm::rotate(90.0f, randVec3 );
d_tfms[i] = glm::rotate(10.0f, randVec4);
```

`d_tfms[i]` is a 4x4 matrix which is then being transferred to the vertex shader as the ModelView matrix.

Before any rotation, this is how my cylinders look like:
(ignore the other shapes, the cylinders here appear as **hollow** 2D circles)

[image]

After the first rotation (90 degrees in the x-axis):

[image]

After the second rotation (10 degrees in the y-axis):

[image]

As you can see, those rotations don't make sense.
In particular, if you look at the dark blue cylinder in the first image vs. the second, it seems like it doesn't rotate around its own local x-axis.

What could be the problem?

Comment: Apart that you showed two assigments for `d_tfms[i]`, you don't show how those cilynders are in world coordinates. By the way, they are not in the same location in world space, so their ModelView matrices are different, even with the same rotation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, answering your question about how to mix 2 rotations, just multiply them (Note: matrix multiplication is *Not* commutative, so matrixA * matrixB is not the same as matrixB * matrixA):
d_tfms[i] = glm::rotate(10.0f, randVec4) * glm::rotate(90.0f, randVec3 );

ps, you may provide the 1st parameter to both functions, which is (in this case) an identity matrix (glm::mat4(1.0)) 
 ie: d_tfms[i] = glm::rotate(glm::mat4(1.0), 10.0f, randVec4) * glm::rotate(glm::mat4(1.0), 90.0f, randVec3 );

Answer (score 0):

d_tfms[i] = glm::rotate(10.0f, randVec4);

This doesn't work for me... do you have the latest version of glm ?

The glm::rotate function has 3 parameters :

- a 4x4 matrix which could be a unit matrix or a transpose matrix(remember the multiply order);
- angle of the rotation;
- a vec3 used to tell which axis you want to rotate;

try to use(at least to be sure if you rotate accordingly):

```
tfms[i] = glm::rotate(tfms[i],glm::radians(90.0f),randVec4);
```

Comment: The version i have of `glm` does not require a matrix as a first parameter. I noticed a problem, however - i tried enabling and disabling the rotations and i noticed that only the last rotation specified is applied, not both. Why is that?

Comment: well ... in glm  rotate, translate and scale stack... i don't know how ... if you declare your matrices outside your loop and apply any of the above to your matrices it will mess up really bad ... try with translates, your figures will go very far away in the distance(don't :))  ) ...

Comment: you should get the latest glm though :D

Comment: What's wrong with declaring the matrices outside of the loop and applying transformations inside?

Comment: its a simple math problem , that is if you know how matrix product works , a pure rotation requires an unit matrix  and that happens in the first run of your loop . In the second run though , your matrix is not a unit matrix anymore . This is my asumption because once i stumbled upon this kind of problem , might not be your main problem here , I am just suggesting you should try that rotate with 3 parameters and declare it in a loop or make it so it will reset its content then you rotate again with a different angle

Comment: you could also map the angle to 2 keys and test the rotation during the rendering , thats usually my first attempt of debugging the rendering process :D...

Comment: Yeah even with the 3 parameters it gives the same result, but your assumption about the way rotation works makes sense. How then do i combine 2 rotations along 2 different axes?

Comment: As Drout says you gotta multiply the matrices , so for 2 axis rotation you create ,for example, a x rotation matrix and a y rotation matrix then you multiply them for the result .

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what i was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: anytime mate :D